# Travis and Eclipse plugins build with maven: corrupted zip file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, travis-ci

I'm trying to deploy Travis on my github project. The project contains a collection of eclipse plugins that I'm assembling with maven. Locally everything works fine, but with Travis I'm encountering a strange problem: it's like the maven local repository has some corrupted files. The output log concerning the error is the following:

```
[ERROR] Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiManifestParserException: Exception parsing OSGi MANIFEST /home/travis/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.12.0.v20160606-1342/org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.12.0.v20160606-1342.jar: zip file is empty -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiManifestParserException: Exception parsing OSGi MANIFEST /home/travis/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.12.0.v20160606-1342/org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.12.0.v20160606-1342.jar: zip file is empty
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiManifestParserException: Exception parsing OSGi MANIFEST /home/travis/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.12.0.v20160606-1342/org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.12.0.v20160606-1342.jar: zip file is empty
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.DefaultBundleReader.doLoadManifest(DefaultBundleReader.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.DefaultBundleReader.loadManifest(DefaultBundleReader.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.EquinoxResolver.loadManifest(EquinoxResolver.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.EquinoxResolver.newState(EquinoxResolver.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.EquinoxResolver.newResolvedState(EquinoxResolver.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiBundleProject.getResolverState(OsgiBundleProject.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiBundleProject.resolveClassPath(OsgiBundleProject.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    ... 11 more
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.DefaultBundleReader.loadManifestFromFile(DefaultBundleReader.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.DefaultBundleReader.doLoadManifest(DefaultBundleReader.java:61)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

do you have any idea on how to solve this? Do you had some previous similar experiences?

Thanks,

S.

Comment: You need to deleted the caches which can be done via travis ui...Are you trying to run your build via `-T ...` of Maven?

Comment: @khmarbaise -T is used to specify the number of threads